# Any way to restrict *.exe files (e.g. software installers) to not ask for admin rights?

Tags: windows-10, installer, non-admin

On my work PC, I can download and run *.exe files as long as they are not detected as malware. Portable program installations also run fine.

Some programs can even be installed normally without problems, i.e. when their installer does not require administrative rights.

Is there any way to run a broader range of installers, which by themselves request administrative rights right from the start, without such rights?

Quite obviously, this is a case where I do not have administrative rights on the PC in question.

Comment: If an installer requires Administrator rights there typically is a reason, it might be an erroneous reason (developer choice as an example), but if required there is no way around it

Answer (score 2):

Two ways, both not recommended :

- Lower the UAC protection level (computer not protected)
- Enable and run under the hidden Administrator account (equally dangerous).

By disabling this protection, you accept to open the door to
viruses and other dangers.